# JWT retrieve for every request or save in redux (or equivalent) store

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, jwt

I am writing a react app and using localStorage (for now) to store a JWT.

My question is is it better to retrieve the token on page load from localStorage and set in the redux store? or should I retrieve it from localStorage on every request.

i.e.

```
const App = () => {
   useEffect(() => {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
      dispatch(setTokenInStore(token))
   })
}
```

Then in each request pull token in from the store and then use it in the requests.

Or the other option is to retrieve the token from localStorage on every request:

```
fetchA = () => {
   const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
   fetch(url, token)
}

fetchB = () => {
   const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
   fetch(url, token)
}
```

If one is better than  the other would it be possible to give reasons. If anything is unclear please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking about the redux store vs localStorage is that they are meant for different purposes. If you need to share state in your app then you go with redux. If you need to persist data in your browser cache then localStorage is the way.

Regarding where to put an jwt-token is a debate iself. The jwts are design to be short lived and IF an external user somehow would get a hold of the token they have a limited time to use it. If its not stored in the localStorage, the user would need to login if they refresh the browser. That would not make a good experience for the end user.

But, If you need authentication in your app you should not reinvent the wheel.
Most jwt-providers can be used with the OpenID Connect layer and there is a lot of docs regarding that [topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID_Connect). For your react app I would there for go with the [react-oidc-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-oidc-client). The client uses its own store (*WebStorageStateStore*) which can be set to localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

If you store tokens in local storage, then it's easily accessible by any XSS attack and any external user can get the token by a script inside your page. You can save JWT token in redux, but mostly redux is used if you want to share the states across the app.

But the general answer to your question would be : try to follow best practices of jwt tokens and security. One main point of security would be setting expiry of your tokens.

There are several blogs which suggest to store tokens in cookies and they are super secure. You can read [here](https://dev.to/gkoniaris/how-to-securely-store-jwt-tokens-51cf).